# Android mobile web app with dynamic graphical buttons

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mobile, html5-canvas

I want to convert a Python/wxPython desktop app I'd written to an Android mobile web app, and would appreciate recommendations on doing this using JQuery Mobile with a PHP back end.  (This is for in-house use so we can specify the mobile devices to be used.)  Specifically:

The existing desktop touchscreen app has an image background with overlaid circular graphical buttons that respond to touch screen (i.e. mouse click) events.  When clicked, the graphic updates by incrementing a counter within the button text, changing the button's background color, and updating a database record.

Would like to use JQuery Mobile for standard menus, etc. and also this graphical button approach to handle tap events as described.  Should I look into HTML5 canvas for this?

I'm comfortable doing web programming using PHP/MySQL, as well as JQM with standard form submissions, but am just getting into events with JQuery, AJAX, etc.
Ready and willing to learn, but don't want to go in too many directions at once on this...

Thanks for your suggestions,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is all more than doable in jQuery Mobile alone without needing to go into the Canvas aspect of things - I quite agree with you about not wanting to go in too many directions!

Firstly you could use all the standard layouts/menus/buttons as you mention for the standard stuff.  In the content of the page for your clickable circles I would just make clickable divs which you could then "listen" to click events for and then process accordingly.

As for making the circles, this can easily be done with the HTML5 border-radius css property which as you mentioned should be easily achievable as all modern mobile browsers support this.  For the sake of the example below I would recommend you view it in a webkit based browser such as Safari, Chrome or a modern version of FF to view the ease of CSS border-radius for creating circles.

I have mocked up a simple example here http://jsbin.com/owipah/44/edit

Naturally you would do whatever post/pre-processing as needed to keep the interface in check with your server-side.

Hope that helps,

R.